# Resend request from spring controller to spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I want to implement such logic: Client sends request to a server that has single controller. That server parses url and according to endpoints chooses another server to process the request. And the second server sends response back the same way.

I want to use Spring Controllers (MVC). I also can have several tomcat servers.

So: Client -> Main Controller that can determine the necessary server with micro services included -> the end server that process request, goes Database etc. -> Main Controller -> Client.

How to make tomcat knows about another tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make tomcat knows about another tomcat?

If that url(url containing another server details) coming from client, then you need to extract it from request and create another httpRequest  and send it to another server(it will be server to server server1>server2) or initiate the redirect request(it will be server1>client>server2) depending upon the requirement.

See [example here to send server to server http request](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

> I also can have several tomcat servers.

You can also consider having multiple webapp with in same tomcat but that depend upon your requirements. Difference will be in this case there will be single jvm process . with multiple tomcat there will be as many number of jvm process.

Comment: Sounds nice but can you explain 'create another httpRequest and send it to another server' part in details?:)

Comment: please see the link i posted